# Publish relationalship data from arcsde

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, spatial-view

I have feature classes and tables having relationship shored in them.(Feature classes has id as which is primary key in other table  ). I want to publish the Feature class as a service on arcgis server 10.1. I want to show the value in place of the id's.what is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on your intentions, but

> I want to show the value in place of the id's.

makes it sound like you should [create a join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s0000002n000000) between the featureclass and table. This will add the table's VALUE field to the featureclass's attribute table, allowing you to access the VALUE via ArcGIS Server.

Comment: I meant ArcSDE View .Could please suggest some links to create SDE View in 10.1.